# Multi-objective optimization: Where to find qualified examples for portfolio management?

Tags: portfolio-management, optimization, algorithm

I am looking for qualified examples of [multi-objective optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization) applied to a  portfolio management situation in non-normal markets. Where can I find one or more examples of such a multi-objective optimization, preferable using some kind of R code (e.g., using [MCO](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mco/mco.pdf) or other packages) but pen and paper examples are equally welcome, including a discussion of required assumptions, limitations and conditions?

If a full example of the above is not known partial references such as examples assuming normal markets or just a discussion on assumptions or limitations would be helpful.